# Qt GUI application build settings in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, mingw, qt-creator

While I develop a small GUI application using Qt Creator (MinGW in Windows), the compilation is successful, and the binary is generated. But application is not ran, it gets crashed.

Below is my configuration setup:
**Qt Version:** 4.8.2
**MinGW:** compilerpath: `C:\MinGW\bin\g++`  debugger: `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb`

If I don't use Qt classes (`QApplication`, `QWidget` or `QString`), it works fine. I mean if I use `std` lib functions, it works fine.

Can any one suggest please?

Comment: Either we guess or you show both code and error.

Answer (score 1):

What is your g++ version? You need to use g++-4.4 with Qt binaries downloaded from their site.